# How to make a series of toggle switches in a scrollable menu with Batch?

Tags: batch-file, menu, toggle

I have spent hours doing this.

```
@echo off
set list = 0 0 1 1
:loop
cls
echo Program Select
echo --------------
set "el=0"
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    set /a "el+=1"
    if %%a equ 0 echo "[ ] Program %el%"
    if %%a equ 1 echo "[X] Program %el%"
)
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo W = Up  /  S = Down  /  L  = Toggle  /  H  = Confirm
choice /C WSLH /N >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 set key=UP
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 2 set key=DN
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 3 set key=SL
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 4 set key=CN
echo %key%
pause >nul
goto loop
```

Now the key variable works fine, and I have yet to implement scrolling, because I can't seem to get it to even render the text.

The goal is to get output like this

```
Program Select
--------------
[ ] Program 1
[ ] Program 2
[X] Program 3
[X] Program 4
----------------------------------------------------
W = Up  /  S = Down  /  L  = Toggle  /  H  = Confirm
```

But instead, I just get the Program Select and the controls. What am I missing?

Comment: its because `set list = 0 0 1 1` is creating a variable called `%list %`  See that trailing space?  Change your line to this `SET "list= 0 0 1 1"` and it will create a variable called `%list%` and fhen the look will process it as sxpected

Comment: Something that's not clear in your question -  are you trying to highlight the current option for selection (but not yet confirmed), the currently selected and confirmed option (single)  or all confirmed selections (multiple)? If dealing with multiple selections, do you intend to build the group as a list or array in order to iterate over the selected group - also if dealing with groups, how are you going to prevent multiple instances of the same selction in the group?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more "meated-out" version of your code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion


:: Program names used

set "program[1]=Program one"
set "program[2]=Program two"
set "program[3]=Program three"
set "program[4]=Program four"
set /a maxprogs=4

:: symbols used for statuses

set "symbols= X"
set "symbolsc=-+"

:restart
:: Set original list status. 0=not selected, 1=selected;

set "list=0 0 1 1"
set /a cursor=1

:loop
cls
echo Program Select
echo --------------
set /a el=0
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    set /a el+=1
    if !el!==%cursor% (set "ds=!symbolsc:~%%a,1!") else (set "ds=!symbols:~%%a,1!")
    call set "progname=%%program[!el!]%%"
    echo [!ds!] !progname!
)
echo ----------------------------------------------------
choice /C WSLHQ /N /M "W = Up  /  S = Down  /  L  = Toggle  /  H  = Confirm / Q = Quit "
set /a key=%errorlevel%
if %key%==5 goto :eof
if %key%==4 goto confirm
if %key%==3 goto toggle
if %key%==2 if %cursor%==%maxprogs% (set /a cursor=1) else set /a cursor+=1
if %key%==1 if %cursor%==1 (set /a cursor=%maxprogs%) else set /a cursor-=1

goto loop

:confirm
echo Confirmed!
set "runany="
set /a el=0
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    set /a el+=1
    if %%a==1 (
     set /a runany+=1
     call set "progname=%%program[!el!]%%"
     echo Run !progname!
    )
)
if not defined runany echo None selected :(

timeout /t 5 /nobreak
goto restart

:toggle
set "newlist="
set /a el=0
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    set /a el+=1
    if !el!==%cursor% (
     if %%a==0 (set "newlist=!newlist! 1") else (set "newlist=!newlist! 0")
    ) else set "newlist=!newlist! %%a"
)
set "list=%newlist%"
goto loop
```

Comments:

`SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion` allows `!var!` to access the changed value of `var` within a loop (`%var%` accesses the *original* value, before the loop started executing).

I used `maxprogs` so that expansion of the list is intuitive - just follow the bouncing ball...

Since the cursor is static, I used `symbols` to represent the non-selected/selected states and `symbolsc` for when the "cursor" is on the state, so `+` is cursor-is-here-it's-selected and `-` is cursor-is-here-it's-not-selected

The `list` usage is similar to your version - `cursor` is for the current cursor-line.

In the display-selections-and-prognames section, note the use of `!el!` to access the *modified* value of `el` within the loop

The tricky bit here is the `call set "progname=%%program[!el!]%%"` statement. This uses a parsing trick to get the value of the program name `el`. Assuming the current value of `el` is `2` for instance, this executes the command `set "progname=%program[2]%"` in a sub-shell by interpreting `%%` as an escaped-`%` and substituting for the *current* value of `el`. The subshell inherits the environment of its caller, so the destination variable is assigned from the calculated value.

I've modified the `choice` command to prompt with the legend, and added Q for Quit as good measure. I'd have used UDTRQ myself, for Up/Down/Toggle/Run/Quit, but something tells me you may not necessarily be using English.

I set `errorlevel` into `key` to avoid having to be particularly careful about maintaining its value, then tested `key` for the only 5 values of interest; on others just beep (from `choice` and present-again.

Quit is obvious; cursor-move simply increments or decrements `cursor` and checks boundary conditions for roll-around.

The other two routines are simply modifications of the display-list routine; the `run` displays the prognames as I have no idea whether you want to run the programs serially or in parallel.

The `toggle` routine uses the same technique to rebuild `list` whilst toggling the `cursor`'th element.

Comment: I like your approach but I prefer to have it be `set "ds=!symbols:~%%a,1!"` then `if !el!==%cursor% (set "aa=*[!ds!]*") else (set "aa= [!ds!] ")` then `echo  !aa! !progname!`  But this is just a matter of preference for the looks. Otherwise I was thinking of writing very similar code, nice work magoo!

Comment: It seems noteworthy that the code here is faster than T3RR0Rs I expected his to be faster since he's holding most of it in memory.  I'm guessing it's because he's writing files to disk and reading them to bother colorizing the code....  Probably if that wasn't the case it woudl be much faster.

Comment: Efficiency of option display in my answer has been addressed by converting the findstr function C_out to a Macro that gets defined into the menu macro

Answer (score 1):

I can understand the desire to format the display of menu's - however I wouldn't recommend the approach your considering. Making a user scroll to the option they want and then confirm it isn't making the script easier for the user.

It is much simpler for a user to select an option from the list with a single keypress. You can easily add a confirmation after the selection where it's critical to confirm an action.

I've developed a template for menu's  (**For Windows 10**) that allows for easy scripting and action of menu options if you'd like to give it a go. A practical GUI script that uses the template is exampled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823099/12343998)

Something that's more in line with the output you want that's done in a simpler way:

---

## Update - Backwards Compatable Version:

Enhanced features:

- Array for menu options supports 36 choice options total
- Color Mode Selection - Colors may now be disabled at runtime.
- Findstr color output for legacy OS converted to a macro for faster execution.

```bat
::: Multi-Use Menu :: Author - T3RRY ::  Version 4.2 :: October 2020 ::
::: %Menu% macro - accepts up to 36 options for selection as quoted Args in list form.
::: parameters to call functions with via a given menu can be supplied using Substring modification as exampled.
::: - Multiple selection of menu items achieved using loops.
::: Tests if a menu option is a label and calls if true.
::: Builds a list of selected options [ that can be deselected ] when used in a loop.
@Echo off & Goto :Main
:::::::::::::::::::::::::: [* Balances Environment stack on script completion *]
:End [Endlocal ^& Set "_End=Y" ^& Exit /B 0]
 Color 07 & %CLOSE%
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Findstr based Colorprint function
::: No longer used within menu macro
::: Unsupported Chars: "<" ">" ":" "\" "/" "?" "&"
:C_out [BG:a-f|0-9][FG:a-f|0-9] ["Quoted Strings" "to print"]
 Set "Str_=%*" &  Set "_Str=" & For %%G in (!Str_!)Do Set "_Str=!_Str! %%~G"
 Set "C_Out=%~1"
 Set "_Str=!_Str:%1 =!" & For /F "Delims=" %%G in ("!_Str!")Do Set "_Str=%%~G"
 For %%G in (!_Str!) Do Set ".Str=%%G"
  If /I "!.Str!" == "Exit"  (Set "C_Out=04") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Next" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Continue" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Back" (Set "C_Out=05") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Return" (Set "C_Out=05")
    <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > " !_Str!"
    findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" " !_Str!" nul
    del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1
    Echo/
Exit /B 0
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Key variable and Macro definition
:main
::::::::::::::::::::: [ For readablities sake - %Menu% macro is built from the following ]:
rem ::: Order of definition must be preserved.
rem [* prepare default findstr color for non windows 10 users *]
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
rem [* default color args for Picked / Not Picked options. Overriden to Echo with Ascii Escape codes if Windows 10 *]
rem [* Color /? for the full combination of colors - BG + FG colors must differ. [BG:a-f|0-9][FG:a-f|0-9] *]
 Set "ColText=For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (Set "_Str="&(Set "C_Out=!Oline:~0,2!" & Set "_Str=!Oline:~3!")&(For %%s in (!_Str!)Do Set ".Str=%%s")&(If /I "!.Str!" == "Exit"  (Set "C_Out=04") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Next" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Continue" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Back" (Set "C_Out=05") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Return" (Set "C_Out=05"))&( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > " !_Str!" )&( findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" " !_Str!" nul )&( del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1 )& Echo/)Else Set Oline="
 Set "_End="

:# Windows Version control. Assigns flag true if system is windows 10 build GTR 10586
:# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#DOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows
:# Version 1511 build number = 10.0.10586
 Set "Win10="
 For /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%v in ('Ver')Do if %%v GTR 10586 Set "Win10=True"

:# If Win10 true ; Test if virtual terminal codes enabled ; enable if false
:# removes win10 flag definition if version does not support Virtual Terminal sequences
:# Reg values: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/
 If defined Win10 (
  Reg Query HKCU\Console | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"VirtualTerminalLevel    REG_DWORD    0x1" > nul || (
    Reg Add HKCU\Console /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ) > Nul && (
    Echo(CMD restart required to enable Virtual terminal sequences.
    Pause
    EXIT
  ) || Set "Win10="
 )

  If defined Win10 For /f %%e in ('Echo(prompt $E^|Cmd') Do Set "\E=%%e"

  If Defined Win10 (
   Set "_nP=Echo/%\E%[90m"& Set "_P=Echo/%\E%[33m"
   Echo/Menu Color mode: [L]egacy [W]indows [D]isabled & For /F "Delims=" %%C in (' Choice /N /C:LWD ')Do (
    If "%%C" =="L" (
     Set "_nP=For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (Set "_Str="&(Set "C_Out=!Oline:~0,2!" & Set "_Str=!Oline:~3!")&(For %%s in (!_Str!)Do Set ".Str=%%s")&(If /I "!.Str!" == "Exit"  (Set "C_Out=04") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Next" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Continue" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Back" (Set "C_Out=05") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Return" (Set "C_Out=05"))&( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > " !_Str!" )&( findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" " !_Str!" nul )&( del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1 )& Echo/)Else Set Oline=08"
     Set "_P=For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (Set "_Str="&(Set "C_Out=!Oline:~0,2!" & Set "_Str=!Oline:~3!")&(For %%s in (!_Str!)Do Set ".Str=%%s")&(If /I "!.Str!" == "Exit"  (Set "C_Out=04") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Next" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Continue" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Back" (Set "C_Out=05") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Return" (Set "C_Out=05"))&( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > " !_Str!" )&( findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" " !_Str!" nul )&( del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1 )& Echo/)Else Set Oline=06"
    )
    If "%%C" =="D" (Set "_nP=Echo/"& Set "_P=Echo/")
   )
  ) Else (
    Set "_nP=For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (Set "_Str="&(Set "C_Out=!Oline:~0,2!" & Set "_Str=!Oline:~3!")&(For %%s in (!_Str!)Do Set ".Str=%%s")&(If /I "!.Str!" == "Exit"  (Set "C_Out=04") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Next" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Continue" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Back" (Set "C_Out=05") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Return" (Set "C_Out=05"))&( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > " !_Str!" )&( findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" " !_Str!" nul )&( del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1 )& Echo/)Else Set Oline=08"
    Set "_P=For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (Set "_Str="&(Set "C_Out=!Oline:~0,2!" & Set "_Str=!Oline:~3!")&(For %%s in (!_Str!)Do Set ".Str=%%s")&(If /I "!.Str!" == "Exit"  (Set "C_Out=04") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Next" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Continue" (Set "C_Out=02") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Back" (Set "C_Out=05") Else If /I "!.Str!" == "Return" (Set "C_Out=05"))&( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > " !_Str!" )&( findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" " !_Str!" nul )&( del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1 )& Echo/)Else Set Oline=06"
    Echo/Menu Color mode: [L]egacy [D]isabled & For /F "Delims=" %%C in (' Choice /N /C:LD ')Do If "%%C" =="D" (Set "_nP=Echo/"& Set "_P=Echo/")
   )
  )

rem [* Menu supports 36 choices using _O array index with substring modification on _Cho var to index choice selection of Array Elements *]
 Set "_Cho=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 Set "DisplayArray=(Echo/!#Sel!| Findstr /LIC:"%%~G" > Nul 2> Nul && ( %_P% [!_Cho:~%%z,1!] X %%~G ) ) || ( %_nP% [!_Cho:~%%z,1!] - %%~G )"
 Set "#Sel=_Nil"
 Set "ClearArray=(For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%i in (' Set Opt[ 2^> Nul ')Do "Set %%i=")"
 Set "ResetVars=(Set "#L=F" &  Set "OptL=" & Set "_O=0")"
 Set "CLOSE=POPD & Endlocal & Set "_End=Y" & Exit /B 0"
 Set "BuildArray=((If !_O! GTR 35 (Call :C_Out 04 "Maximum options [!_O!] Exceeded" & (Timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK) & %CLOSE%))&Set "OptL=!OptL!!_Cho:~%%z,1!"&Set "Opt[!_Cho:~%%z,1!]=%%~G")"
 Set "MakeChoice=(For /F "Delims=" %%C in ('Choice /N /C:!OptL!')Do findstr.exe /BLIC:":!Opt[%%C]!" "%~F0" > nul 2> nul && Call :!Opt[%%C]! "Param" 2> Nul || ((Echo/"!#Sel!"| Findstr /LIC:"!Opt[%%C]!" > Nul 2> Nul && (For /F "Delims=" %%r in ("!Opt[%%C]!")Do If Not "!#Sel!" == "" (Set "#Sel=!#Sel:"%%r"=!")Else (Set "#Sel=_Nil"))) || (Set "#Sel=!#Sel! "!Opt[%%C]!"")))"
 Set "Return=For /L %%s in (0 1 4)Do (If not "!#Sel!" == "" (If "!#Sel:~0,1!" == " " (If "!#L!" == "F" (Set "#Sel=!#Sel:~1!"))Else (Set "#L=T"))Else (Set "#Sel=_Nil"))&if not "!#Sel!" == "_Nil" if not "!#Sel!" == "" (Set "#Sel=!#Sel:_Nil=!")"
 Set "Menu=(If defined _End Goto :End) &For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%ClearArray% & %ResetVars% &(For %%G in (!Options!)Do For %%z in (!_O!)Do %BuildArray% & %DisplayArray% &Set /A "_O+=1")& %MakeChoice% & %Return% )Else Set Options="
 For %%M in ( ClearArray ResetVars BuildArray DisplayArray MakeChoice Return )Do Set "%%M="
 IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\colorize" md "%TEMP%\colorize"
 PUSHD "%TEMP%\colorize" || (Echo/"%TEMP%\colorize" Could not be found & %CLOSE%)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & REM [* required to be activated AFTER definition of Macro's. *]
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Commence script main body | Demonstration of usages
:Loop
rem [* doublequoting of options recommended - Required for strings containing standard delimiters. *]
 If not defined _End cls
 If not defined _End %ColText%05 Make a selection.
rem [* Param Substring modification examples passing parameters to labels called when selected - Optional feature. *]
 Set /A "PRM=!Random! %%100 + 100" & Rem [* Example param only *]
 %Menu% "Exit" "Next" "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4"
 Echo/"!#Sel!" | Findstr.exe /LIC:"Exit" > Nul 2> Nul && (Goto :End)
Goto :Loop
 
:Next
rem [* Selection of a single option occurs by using the macro without a loop or resetting the #Sel variable
rem - between %menu% use and next iteration of a loop *]
rem [* Process #Sel items using the !#Sel! variable - then ** SET "#Sel-_Nil" prior to next usage of Menu macro** *]
 Set "Menu1Opts=!#Sel!"
 Set "#Sel="
 Cls
 Call :C_Out 03 "Selected =" !Menu1opts!
 %Menu% "Exit" " + Continue" ".. Back"
 Echo/!#Sel! | Findstr.exe /LIC:".. Back" > Nul 2> Nul && (Set "#Sel=!Menu1opts!"& Exit /B 0)
 Echo/!#Sel! | Findstr.exe /LIC:"Exit" > Nul 2> Nul && (%CLOSE%)
 Set "#Sel="
 Echo/!Menu1opts! | Findstr.exe /LIC:"_Nil" > Nul 2> Nul && (Call :C_Out 04 "Selection Required."&(Pause & Exit /B 0)) || Call :C_Out 02 "Confirmed=" !Menu1opts!
 Call :C_Out 02 "Example complete."
 Pause
rem [* to exit at end of script or by user selection *]
 %CLOSE%
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: End of example
```

Output:

[image: selection differentiation]

Comment: This is absolutely great, but unfortunately I want to keep compatibility with older versions of Windows (which I believe the color doesn't work with), and this also doesn't really work with the application I am developing. I realize there are other better languages for this, but I decided on Batch for a few reasons that I won't get in to here.

Comment: Fair enough - details such as those are best added to the main body of your question. There is a method of coloring text by line that's compatible with older windows versions which uses findstr, that wouldn't take much to modify the above to use. As for "this doesn't really work with the application I am developing", beyond backwards compatibility, I can't see how this type of method wouldn't be compatible. Care to elaborate on why?

Comment: @GabrielKeess answer updated to support windows 10 and older versions, without hindering performance on windows 10 systems.

Comment: Example usage also expanded to demonstrate how to reuse the menu for single item selection, after the intial selection has been transfered to a new variable.

Comment: This is neat, but not quite what he wants.  You could tweak this code to meet the requirements of the question as stated though.  Strangely I find it funny that the macros are slower than functions I would have thought hem to be faster as they're all in memory.

Comment: I expected your to be faster since you're holding most of it in memory.  I'm guessing it's because you're writing files to disk and reading them to bother colorizing the code....  Probably if that wasn't the case it would be much faster.

Comment: It would indeed be simple enough to modify the output string based on the status to output `{i} [ ]`  or `{i} [X]` as opposed to just the `[index]`.  So simple in fact that the OP should be able to see where to modify the output string in the DiplayArray variable to achieve that output style.

Comment: For non windows 10, the Call to C_Out and redirections drastically slow things down, but the other hold up is the pipe to findstr of the #Sel list variable for the conditional testing that flags an option string as selected or not. - An approach that easily accomodates multiple selections of unkown strings. For windows 10 users, VT codes are used to output Options rather than calling the C_Out function. Have repoisitioned the `PUSHD "%TEMP%\Colorize"` and `POPD` commands outside of the C_out function for [marginally] faster performance.

Comment: @BenPersonick I've updated the script to use macro versions of the Findstr C_Out function within the menu macro for non windows 10 users. Speed greatly improved. Also replaced `+` with `X` for a more prominent character based emphasis on the option/s selected. I'm not inclined to modify for a `[ ]` or `[X]` flag style, as it's not a suitable output style for something that's built as a generic use menu for single or multiple selection menu's.

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other here.  In my 1st comment I was not speaking about formatting of the tick boxes. (I agree those are a matter of flavor, Op could change them easily, and I don't consider that essential to answering the Op's question.)  What I mean is the OP clearly wants a solution, along the lines of the answer by @Magoo - Where the user actually navigates a list with `W` and `S` and select with `L` (Although I suspect OP would be happy if `up arrow` and `down arrow` and select with `spacebar` used to toggle as that is common in the sort of menu they are looking for)

Comment: I tried the new code and it's still quite slow, surprisingly so, especially since we are selecting by choosing the actual choices you would expect the user to be able to enter fast inputs, but you have a much slower load time on your menu than magoo, which seems strange as you're operating mostly in memory, however the colorization for legacy OS  is the draw back, as it requires writing to disk, which is the obviously slowest operation possible to perform, and then reading from disk many times, which is the next slowest, throwing away all the benefits of having this as an in memory operation.

Comment: I get that you took a windows 10 method which wouldn't have this problem and adapted it to legacy OS, but while on windows 10 making it all a macro probably had a viable effect because of the windows 10 colorization, but it here it fails to bring much of value ot the table other than it's your preferred style.  I feel certain that if you removed the colorization then you could make a much snappier UI, and could probably allow inputs more quickly than Magoo, who currently is about 1 input per 0.5 seconds, verses yours which is about 1 input per second and will take longer with more entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223376/discussion-between-t3rr0r-and-ben-personick).